# Can't close open3d window on Mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, open3d

after run

```
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(...)
```

on jupyter notebook getting the following error:

> [Open3D WARNING] GLFW Error: Cocoa: Failed to find service port for
> display

when try to close open3d window.
The window stay open (Not Responding) till kernel restart.

on:

```
Mac M2 Pro, 
Python 3.8.16,
open3d 0.17.0,
IPython 8.3.0,
ipykernel 6.9.1,
jupyter_client 7.2.2
jupyter_core 4.10.0
jupyter_server 2.7.0
notebook 6.5.4.
```

found following GitHub issues:
[1673](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/1673) , [4813](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/4813)

Answer (score 0):

It usually occurs when there is a mismatch between the OpenGL context and the macOS system display settings.
Update Open3D, Make sure your Jupyter Notebook and its dependencies are up to date , and Verify your macOS system display settings to ensure they are set correctly. Go to "System Preferences" > "Displays," and check the resolution and refresh rate settings.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't change any "Displays"setting on the macOS. additionally I just install the current Jupyter Notebook, so it should be the last stable one.